# Разбираю чужой код для решения задачи на алгоритм Хаффмана. Есть места в которых не могу понять, как это работает

Tags: python, алгоритм, синтаксис

Задача:
По данной непустой строке s длины не более 10^4, состоящей из строчных букв латинского алфавита, постройте оптимальный беспрефиксный код. В первой строке выведите количество различных букв kk, встречающихся в строке, и размер получившейся закодированной строки. В следующих kk строках запишите коды букв в формате "letter: code". В последней строке выведите закодированную строку.

Вопрос 1.

Почему у метода 'walk' класса 'Node' атрибуты после 'self.left' опять через точку ссылаются на 'walk'? Это рекурсия такая?

Вопрос 2.

Как работает обход дерева 'root.walk(code, "")', почему вызывая 'walk' и указывая в скобках 'code' (type(code) - set), в этом атрибуте происходит добавление в множество (set) в результате обхода дерева? ведь таких функций нигде не указано.

```
    code = {}  # инициализируем словарь кодов символов
    if h:  # если строка пустая, то очередь будет пустая и обходить нечего
        [(_freq, _count, root)] = h  # в очереди 1 элемент, приоритет которого не важен, а сам элемент - корень дерева
        root.walk(code, "")  # обойдем дерева от корня и заполним словарь для получения кодирования Хаффмана
```

## Чужой код - решение

```
# put your python code here
import heapq  # модуль для работы с мин. кучей из стандартной библиотеки Python
from collections import Counter  # словарь в котором для каждого объекта поддерживается счетчик
from collections import namedtuple

# добавим классы для хранения информации о структуре дерева
# воспользуемся функцией namedtuple из стандартной библиотеки
class Node(namedtuple("Node", ["left", "right"])):  # класс для ветвей дерева - внутренних узлов; у них есть потомки
    def walk(self, code, acc):
        # чтобы обойти дерево нам нужно:
        self.left.walk(code, acc + "0")  # пойти в левого потомка, добавив к префиксу "0"
        self.right.walk(code, acc + "1")  # затем пойти в правого потомка, добавив к префиксу "1"

class Leaf(namedtuple("Leaf", ["char"])):  # класс для листьев дерева, у него нет потомков, но есть значение символа
    def walk(self, code, acc):
        # потомков у листа нет, по этому для значения мы запишем построенный код для данного символа
        code[self.char] = acc or "0"  # если строка длиной 1 то acc = "", для этого случая установим значение acc = "0"

def huffman_encode(s):  # функция кодирования строки в коды Хаффмана
    h = []  # инициализируем очередь с приоритетами
    for ch, freq in Counter(s).items(): # постоим очередь с помощью цикла, добавив счетчик, уникальный для всех листьев
        h.append((freq, len(h), Leaf(ch)))  # очередь будет представлена частотой символа, счетчиком и самим символом
    heapq.heapify(h)  # построим очередь с приоритетами
    count = len(h) # инициализируем значение счетчика длиной очереди
    while len(h) > 1:  # пока в очереди есть хотя бы 2 элемента
        freq1, _count1, left = heapq.heappop(h)  # вытащим элемент с минимальной частотой - левый узел
        freq2, _count2, right = heapq.heappop(h)  # вытащим следующий элемент с минимальной частотой - правый узел
        # поместим в очередь новый элемент, у которого частота равна суме частот вытащенных элементов
        heapq.heappush(h, (freq1 + freq2, count, Node(left, right))) # добавим новый внутренний узел у которого
                                                                     # потомки left и right соответственно
        count += 1  # инкрементируем значение счетчика при добавлении нового элемента дерева
    code = {}  # инициализируем словарь кодов символов
    if h:  # если строка пустая, то очередь будет пустая и обходить нечего
        [(_freq, _count, root)] = h  # в очереди 1 элемент, приоритет которого не важен, а сам элемент - корень дерева
        root.walk(code, "")  # обойдем дерева от корня и заполним словарь для получения кодирования Хаффмана
    return code  # возвращаем словарь символов и соответствующих им кодов

def main():
    s = input()  # читаем строку длиной  до 10**4
    code = huffman_encode(s)  # кодируем строку
    encoded = "".join(code[ch] for ch in s)  # отобразим закодированную версию, отобразив каждый символ
                                             # в соответствующий код и конкатенируем результат
    print(len(code), len(encoded))  # выведем число символов и длину закодированной строки
    for ch in sorted(code): # обойдем символы в словаре в алфавитном порядке с помощью функции sorted()
        print("{}: {}".format(ch, code[ch]))  # выведем символ и соответствующий ему код
    print(encoded)  # выведем закодированную строку

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: во первых не атрибуты а методы, во вторых не ссылаются, это и есть вызов метода `walk`, рекурсивный, зашли в ноду, от нее дальше влево\вправо, как ветви. и у метода `walk`, описанного в классе `Leaf`, идет присвоение чего то чему то, может отсюда

Comment: 2. При передаче в функцию списка или словаря на самом деле туда передаётся ссылка на такой объект (а не его копия, как вы могли бы подумать), и все дальнейшие действия со списком/словарём отражаются на исходном объекте. Поэтому после возврата из всех этих рекурсий в словаре будет всё, что туда будет записано через code[self.char] = acc or "0"